First and second fundamental form equal
In a certain exercise I have been asked to show that there cannot be any surface $S$ such that for a parametrization $\alpha(u,v)$ the coefficients of the First Fundamental Form, $E,F,G$ and of the second one, $e,f,g$ are $E = v^2, F = 0, G = 1$ and $e = v^2, f = 0, g = 1$.

I have no idea of how to start. I tried maybe differentiating with respect to any variable the scalar products $\alpha_u \cdot \alpha_v$ and so on, and maybe reaching that they cannot be the same in this case, but I don't know how to proceed. I would be grateful for any hint.

Try using Codazzi equations

I don't know what are those equations. Isn't there any other method?

Please look up the Codazzi or the Codazzi-Mainardi equations. Offhand, I don't see how else to do this.

It's impossible to know what tools you have to use. As Deane's comments suggest, the standard methods may or may not be known to you. My answer gives what is to me the most obvious solution, but once again we cannot know if you have these tools.

The definition of the Gaussian curvature  $K=\dfrac{\det\mathbf{II}}{\det\mathbf I}$, gives us $K=1$. However, the first fundamental form leads to Gaussian curvature $0$, using this standard formula:
$$K=-\frac1{2\sqrt{EG}}\left(\Big(\frac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}\Big)_v +
\Big(\frac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}}\Big)_u\right).$$
Alternatively, if the first and second fundamental forms are equal, then the shape operator, whose matrix representation is $S = {\mathbf I}^{-1}\mathbf{II}$, will be the identity at every point. It's a standard straightforward result that a connected surface with this property is (up to translation) a subset of the unit sphere (which we know has Gaussian curvature $1$).
Maybe you can argue directly that there is no parametrization $\alpha$ of the unit sphere with the given $E,F,G$, but I don't see it immediately.

Nice. Didn’t think of that.
